# executing scripts in remote_api for app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, remoteapi

I would like to use the remote_api in python app engine to upload some 4000 entities to the ndb datastore from my desktop.The instructions are quite clear on how to use remote_api shell from this article (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api). But I want to write a script to upload all my entities. I cant seem to figure out how to execute a script.so how do I run a script that I've written?? Any help will be much appreciated.I'm a newbie at python and linux. :)

Comment: Since you can use the remote shell, why not just simply do `import my_script` once you're there?

Comment: @DanielRoseman ,well that worked ..I now see this was a dumb question :| .

Answer (score 0):

You may use the appcfg.py tool with the option upload_data by passing a CSV file containing your data.

You should previously create a bulkloader file (create_bulkloader_config option) and change it to your needs before using it.

Comment: I tried that method previously, but I couldn't figure how to specify the keyname of each entity myself(I want to query entities by name).So I switched to remote_api.Does upload_data have any significant advantage??

Comment: Although possible, you should not provide the key ("__key__" property) yourself, and let Datastore to assign one to each entity.

Later you'll run a call to query() with the property Name while querying on proper keys would be done by calling get().

You can use NDB or pure Datastore calls.

I haven't tried to upload data from a CSV yet, but if I have time, I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Thanks,that would be awesome,If you do get around to it,please post the code somewhere.

Comment: I was unable to upload a CSV, it has to be in a sqlite format from previously downloaded data. Do you have those 4000 entities in a local Datastore?

Comment: Nope.As a CSV file .but I was able to upload it to the datastore of my local app engine (local host:8080) using remoteapi ,if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Then, supposedly, you could download it from your local dev server with the download_data option in a sqlite format (but specific for Datastore bulkloader) and upload it to the App Engine platform with the upload_data.

Comment: OK.I'll try that. But why would I do this and not just directly upload to app engine using remote api?

Comment: It's a suggested workaround. The remote_api sounds better option, of course.